# Should I use sockets in client/server application?

Tags: java, sockets, security

> Similar: [Socket vs HTTP based communication for a mobile client/server application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5334680/socket-vs-http-based-communication-for-a-mobile-client-server-application)

I'm currently working on a Java client-server based program (with the intention to turn it into an Android app). I've successfully implemented the server engine, and the clients beautifully connects and exchange data. My implementation is base upon [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13116162/1751640) answer of mine.

The drawback is, all communication is done directly with sockets, no protocol at all. Is this the accepted, secure - or professional - way of client-server communication?

Even further, in case I want to accept credit cards, PayPal or Google Wallet, will my app be compliant with their security standards as I don't use SSL? What about if I'll use my own level of security, say `javax.crypto.CipherOutputStream`?

Comment: Might consider wrapping your messages in a container format like [protocol buffers](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/?hl=en) and encrypting those.

Comment: You _could_ support two protocols: your socket based and http(s). Use one of them where appropriate. But perhaps a standard like REST or mqtt has wider support, you didn't mention the pros for your own implementation.

Comment: @Marged Yeah, don't laugh, but the pro is that i don't have to learn new things... Also I have full control over everything, since I implemented all myself.

Comment: That is a definite advantage. Are you able to handle unsteady and unreliable connections ? If not go for a different protocol.

Comment: Yes, I defined an authentication system, before connecting.

Comment: @Marged Which part is an advantage?

Comment: I meant wireless connections with interruptions and small transfer rates. All you wrote is an advantage but you need to be careful not to add to your solution what a standard already contains.

Comment: @Marged Hmmm, hardly understood you. Please elaborate.

Comment: @Marged Why don't you write an answer? Seems like you have much to say on this subject.

Comment: A large advantage of using a commonly used protocol/library is that it's been out in the wild and battle tested. There's risk involved in implementing your own things no matter how competent you are.

Comment: @Gendarme Thanks for your encouragement. I gave it a shot.

Comment: I assume by "app" you mean something that is not browser based and more a standalone application (like apk on Android)

Comment: you don't have to use HTTP or whatever. If necessary, you can add SSL on top of your socket for end-to-end encryption, which is rather simple. So don't sweat it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is on the verge of being too broad, but anyway ;-) As we don't know the "quality" and depth of your own socket based communication protocol it is hard to tell if it is able to "compete" with other protocols. So lets just assume that you took care of the necessary stuff and your server is able to handle many parallel connections and follows "best-practice".

I see **advantages** in implementing ones own protocol, you already mentioned them:

- it is based on something you already know and feel comfortable with (sockets)
- you have full control and don't depend on any framework
- you know the "guts" of your implementation and are the first authority when questions arise

But there are certainly **disadvantages** and risks:

- not only *can* you do everything, this can soon become a *must*
- your protocol needs to work well outside laboratory conditions. In the real world you won't see the quality of wired or Wifi networks. 2G/3G/4G networks can be unstable, interruptions occur and transfer speeds can be slow
- Some environments might have problems with non-http(s) traffic

If your reason for implementing your own socket based protocol was efficiency there are other protocols that are not "chatty" and work on a bytelevel. You could have a look at MQTT for example if you really consider a replacement.

If you are not allergic to http you can have a look at REST over https.

But no matter which protocol you consider "fit" for the main communication of your application: you can always mix in http(s) for services that demand for this.

Comment: This is a full quality answer; thanks, I'll accept it.

Comment: But how could you implement a http protocol with a server/client type of behaviour? Does it need a name domain?

Answer (score 0):

WebSocket is a low-level protocol, think of it as a socket on the web. Every thing, including a simple request/response design pattern, how to create/update/delete resources need, status codes etc to be build on top of it. All of these are well defined for HTTP.

**WebSocket is a stateful protocol where as HTTP is a stateless protocol.**

WebSocket connections are know to scale vertically on a single server where as HTTP can scale horizontally. There are some proprietary solutions for WebSocket horizontal scaling, but they are not standards-based.
HTTP comes with a lot of other goodies such as caching, routing, multiplexing, gzipping and lot more. All of these need to be defined on top of WebSocket.
How will Search Engine Optimization (SEO) work with WebSocket ? Works very well for HTTP URLs.
All proxy, DNS, firewalls are not yet fully aware of WebSocket traffic. They allow port 80 but might restrict traffic by snooping on it first.
Security with WebSocket is all-or-nothing approach.

Comment: But I have my own implementation of socket connection. I want to know if it is advisable to use?

Answer (score 0):

A better approach might be to replace the sockets based connection with a RESTFul API that performs the same functions. Using that approach you will be able to use PayPal and accept credits. Also, you can more standard methods, like Ouath2, to handle authentication. It also works well with Android, to have a RESTful api to communicate with the server component.